# What are the Excel equivalents to MS Word commands?

Tags: excel

MS Word has two useful search and pattern matching features:

1. find by color
2. find using wildcards, and specifically the reverse of
   a value, such as [!*#*] that finds a string that does not have the
   value *#*

Currently, I use Excel conditional formatting to colorize a target value.

Then I copy the Excel table to a Word table to change the colored value to a new string, such as *#*.

Then I use Word-Find-Wildcards to delete every cell in the Word table that is not *#* by using [!*#*].

Then I copy the results back to Excel for further processing.

Is there an Excel formula equivalent to Word's:

- find by color
- find and delete all cells that do not match a pattern

Hope to avoid using VB, but will do so to minimize the round-tripping with Word.

Comment: While this may be better suited for `SuperUser`, Excel's [Find](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/912-excel-filter-by-cell-color.html) feature has Format option. Deleting all cells at once that match a pattern will require VBA. The Find function can also handle *some* sophisticated pattern matching. I don't have any links off-hand though.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is able to search by color.
When you do `CTRL + F`, click `Options>>` and then click the `Format` button.

As for the other issue, perhaps you could reverse the logic of your conditional formatting?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but I need to solve both at the same time - it's a 'workflow' issue. My goal is to do all transformations in Excel. But the two above only work in Word and need to be performed in sequence. So I may have to continue to do these transforms in Word.